# Cross Language Troll

Tags: code-challenge

**The Setup**
Jim the student who attempts to use Stack Overflow to do his homework has asked how to get his program to say "Hello World" in under 100 lines of code, you decide mere mortal trolling is not enough...

**The Challenge**
You need to provide Jim with a program less than 100 lines long that outputs a satisfactory answer in another language. Bonus points for additional languages.

**The Rules**
 1. Max 100 lines of code
 2. 10 points for successfully outputting the answer in another language
 3. +1 point for every additional language answer is provided for
 4. Honorable mentions will be given to the most creative, most evil, and most unorthodox answers
 5. Challenge ends 23:59pm GMT 3/14/2014 (results provided a few hours post challenge)

The winner is Michael who converted between six languages first

I also will give an honorable mention for cleverness to McMillin for using one command that works in several languages

I also give an honorable mention to Comintern... I don't actually know if brownies is a language, but I think we can agree it was unorthodox.

I don't think any of the answers qualifies as evil, but for the sake of it everyone who used brainfuckery will be considered recipients.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. We reserve the `code-golf` tag for challenges strictly scored by least number of bytes/characters. `Code-trolling` also fails to apply here since the task you have set up is a straightforward polyglot. The only trolling involved is introduced by your backstory. Look at some past code-trolling questions; usually the aim is to do a simple task in a way that embodies/parodies common programming pitfalls, easily missed bugs, abuse of paradigms, non-idiomatic coding, etc. At its best, code-trolling should be about showing your skill by astute parody of the unskilled approach.

Comment: My apologies, I thought it fit code-trolling section, I'll be more careful about future tagging.

Comment: By another language you mean? A programming language or natural langauge? Also, what about languages that share the same keyword to print (e.g. 'print' in several languages)

Comment: Well my intended purpose was from one programming language to another, but also different natural languages would be even more trollish. Shared solutions... since I didn't specify so long as you properly credit that you covered the language I'll count it.

Comment: I think you should clarify your rule as programming language. I posted my answer only because I thought it would be funny, I didn't even expect you to consider it a valid answer.

Comment: the best answer to this would be a unicode aware hq9 interpreter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### JavaScript to C to PHP to JavaScript to Brainfuck to HQ9+

```javascript
atob("bWFpbigpe3B1dHMoImVjaG8gXCJjb25zb2xlLmxvZygnKysrKysrWz4rKysrKysrKysrKys8LV0+LicpO1wiOyIpO30=")
```

This outputs :

```
main(){puts("echo \"console.log('++++++[>++++++++++++<-]>.');\";");}
```

Which outputs :

```php
echo "console.log('++++++[>++++++++++++<-]>.');";
```

Which outputs :

```javascript
console.log('++++++[>++++++++++++<-]>.');
```

Which outputs :

```javascript
++++++[>++++++++++++<-]>.
```

Which outputs :

```
H
```

Which outputs :

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 17):

### Bash

```
echo Bonjour tout le monde
```

Outputs "Hello World" in a language called [French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language).

Comment: Oops... I thought it was a code-trolling question. I just realised this was retagged. Apologies if you think this is not an answer.

Comment: French language? Is it a LISP dialect?

Answer (score 5):

### C# -> [Chef](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/chef.html) -> German\Brownies

```cpp
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Greetings
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] ingredients = {" vegetable oil "," eggs "," boiling water "," vanilla "," cocoa powder "," flour "," sugar "," baking soda "," salt "};
        static string[] measures = {" tablespoons"," dashes"," heaped tablespoons",""," pinches"};
        static int[] amounts = {154,32,157,127,110,145,164,141,154};
        static int[] units = {0,3,0,1,2,2,2,4,4};
        static int[] steps = {4,7,0,8,2,1,3,5,0,6};

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Fudge Brownies.\n\nThis recipe makes an absurd amount of brownies for one person.\n");
            sb.Append("\nPre-heat oven to 175 degrees Celsius.\n\nIngredients.\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(amounts[i]);
                sb.Append(measures[units[i]]);
                sb.Append(ingredients[i]);
                sb.Append("\n");
            }

            sb.Append("\nMethod.\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < steps.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("Put");
                sb.Append(ingredients[steps[i]]);
                sb.Append("into the mixing bowl.\n");
            }

            sb.Append("Liquefy contents of the mixing bowl.\nPour contents of the mixing bowl into the baking dish.\n");
            sb.Append("\nCooking time: time 40 minutes.\n\nServes 1.");
            Console.WriteLine(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

The C# code above outputs the Chef code below (which is also [a pretty tasty brownie recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/fudgy-brownies-i/)).

```
Fudge Brownies.

This recipe makes an absurd amount of brownies for one person.

Pre-heat oven to 175 degrees Celsius.

Ingredients.
154 tablespoons vegetable oil
32 eggs
157 tablespoons boiling water
127 dashes vanilla
110 heaped tablespoons cocoa powder
145 heaped tablespoons flour
164 heaped tablespoons sugar
141 pinches baking soda
154 pinches salt

Method.
Put cocoa powder into the mixing bowl.
Put baking soda into the mixing bowl.
Put vegetable oil into the mixing bowl.
Put salt into the mixing bowl.
Put boiling water into the mixing bowl.
Put eggs into the mixing bowl.
Put vanilla into the mixing bowl.
Put flour into the mixing bowl.
Put vegetable oil into the mixing bowl.
Put sugar into the mixing bowl.
Liquefy contents of the mixing bowl.
Pour contents of the mixing bowl into the baking dish.

Cooking time: time 40 minutes.

Serves 1.
```

The hardest part was doing the unit conversions on the recipe, and it really does make an absurd amount of brownies, even for a whole bunch of people.  When run through a [Chef interpreter](https://metacpan.org/release/Acme-Chef), it outputs:

```
Hallo Welt
```

Or, "Hello World" in German. I'm not sure if "brownies" technically constitutes a language.  If it does, it probably isn't Turing complete.

Answer (score 2):

## Fortran 95 to Batch back to Fortran 95

```
open(unit=11,file="FOO.BAT")
write(11,"(A)") "@ECHO OFF"
write(11,"(A)") 'ECHO print*, "Hello World!"; end > BAR.F95'
call SYSTEM("FOO.BAT")
call SYSTEM("gfortran BAR.F95 -o BAR.EXE")
call SYSTEM("BAR.EXE")
end
```

This code produces a file named FOO.BAT, and then executes it automatically. This .BAT file will generate another file named BAR.F95, which is a Fortran code. This code is automatically compiled and executed, finally producing the phrase "Hello World!"

Comment: I think you mean Batch, not Bash.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

## C++/JavaScript/Python 3

A oneliner:

```
int main(){puts("alert(\"print(\\\"Hello World!\\\")\")");}
```

Output is a program in JavaScript that outputs the basic Hello World program in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

**Perl/Ruby/Python(2)/Fortran/SML**

```
print "Hello World";
```